# Delete matching two regular expressions on the same field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to delete documents but with multiple condition at the same variable.

```
db.getCollection('system_parameter').remove(
{
    "variable":/^pickup_kota/,
    "variable":
    {
        $nin:
        [
            /^pickup_kota_jakarta/
        ]
    }
}
```

)

What I'm trying to do is, I want to delete all the data with the same prefix ('pickup_kota'), but excluding the ('pickup_kota_jakarta') documents.

If I execute the query above, ALL of the data is removed including let's say prefix 'some_doc' but excluding 'pickup_kota_jakarta'

Comment: This is what [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is actually for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All MongoDB query arguments are already AND conditions, so just include them on the same key:

```
db.getCollection('system_parameter').remove({
  "variable": { 
    "$regex": /^pickup_kota/,
    "$nin": [
      /^pickup_kota_jakarta/
    ]
  }
})
```

Or you can always write the "long form" with [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

```
db.getCollection('system_parameter').remove({
  "$and": [
    { "variable": /^pickup_kota/ },
    { "variable": "$nin": [/^pickup_kota_jakarta/] }
  ]
})
```

So with two documents like this:

```
{ "variable" : "pickup_kota_somewhere" }
{ "variable" : "pickup_kota_jakarta" }
```

Only the first one gets removed

But as long as you can use a different operator such as [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex) here to separate the conditions onto keys, then you don't need the full form.

Also since those are both anchored to the start of the string, it's more efficient for MongoDB to do the two comparisons than attempting a regular expression to meet both possible conditions. The only regular expression that could would break that bounding rule, and obviate the efficiency gained by searching anchored to the beginning of the string which can use an index.

Comment: I tried to do both of them, but it removed 0 documents.

Comment: @Rifi331 I tried it too and it selects the correct document, being with a variable field value like: `"pickup_kota_somewhere"` and of course not the one ending in jakarta. So it works for me and you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh! my bad, I haven't add the other cities.

Answer (score 0):

You can try $all operator.

```
db.getCollection('system_parameter').remove({
  "variable": {$all: [
               {$regex: /^pickup_kota/},
               {$nin:[/^pickup_kota_jakarta/]} 
              ]}
})
```